# Login to Twitter using requests returns "too many redirects"

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to login to Twitter using requests. I have a working code to login to Twitter in PHP, so I was trying to convert it, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
url = "https://twitter.com/login"
url_login = "https://twitter.com/sessions"
user_login = "user"
user_password = "pass"
user_agent = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
                  "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36")
accept_language = 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4'

response = s.get(url)

posicion_token = response.text.find("authenticity_token")

print "El token es"

print response.text[posicion_token+27:posicion_token+67]

token = response.text[posicion_token+27:posicion_token+67]

login_post = {'session[username_or_email]' : user_login,
                   'session[password]' : user_password,
                   'return_to_ssl':'true',  
                   'scribe_log':'',
                   'redirect_after_login':'%2F',
                   'authenticity_token':token
                   }

print login_post

s.headers.update ({'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
                        'Accept-Language' : accept_language,
                        'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
                        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Host' : 'www.twitter.com',
                        'Origin' : 'https://www.twitter.com',
                        'Referer' : 'https://www.twitter.com/',
                        'User-Agent' : user_agent
                        })

login = s.post(url_login, data=login_post, allow_redirects=True)
```

The error I get is

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\instabot-twitbot\logueo_twitter.py", line
>   52, in 
>       login = s.post(url_login, data=login_post, allow_redirects=True)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555,
>   in post
>       return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508,
>   in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in
>   send
>       history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 140, in
>   resolve_redirects
>       raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded %s redirects.' % self.max_redirects, response=resp) TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30
>   redirects.

Comment: have you tried to put something in "redirect_after_login" ?

Comment: @2oppin tried now "true", "false", it does the same. In the code I have working in PHP that variable being filled like I have it here works.

Comment: maybe the reason in cookies, can you share working PHP example to compare? BTW why you not using twitter OAuth API instead?

Comment: @2oppin hard to explain, I need to approve an app to a twitter account and login to the control panel of that app to perform a task that the app performs semi automatically right now and I want it full automatic. The code in PHP which works to login is here https://m.mediafire.com/view/ss031irlyocdlrl